# Skrollr affect fade in when a certain distance from the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using skrollr and I have a div at the bottom of some content that I want to fade in once the screen gets down to its level.

I tried all kid of examples using there cheat sheet with no success.

Its located above the footer (500px from the bottom) and it is pushed from the top different amounts based on the content so I can't tell how far it will be from the top.

I have tried

```
<div ... data-bottom-top="opacity: 0" data-center-top="opacity: 1">
```

I have easily used it to elements at the top of the screen (fades out when scrolled down a certain amount) but can't seem to figure it out from the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using absolute mode, you can try the data-end attribute.  For example, if your div is located 500px from the bottom, your code could look like
    `data-500-end="opacity:1`

You can see the documentation I'm referencing [here](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr#absolute-mode-or-document-mode).